# How do I validate my bash script to show that only 2 file names can be typed when user is prompted or errors out with echo statement

Tags: bash, parameters, compare, echo, filenames

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Ask for user to enter two filenames

echo Please Provide 2 filenames to compare

read file1 file2

# Check to see if 2 different filenames are not provided
```

Comment: I know I need to do if statement to say something along the lines of if file1 and file 2 are not equal to 2 then print error message

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Please Provide 2 filenames to compare"

read file1 file2
if [ "$file1" == "$file2" ]
then
  echo "ERROR: file names must be different."
  exit 1
fi

echo "Good stuff!"
# Bash returns result of "echo" function here, which is 0 (success)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -rp 'Please enter 2 filenames to compare: ' -a file; do
  if ! (( ${#file[*]} == 2 )); then
    printf >&2 'You entered %s file, need 2 files, please try again!\n' "${#file[*]}"
  elif [[ ${file[0]} == ${file[1]} ]]; then
    printf >&2 'Both %s and %s are the same, please try again!\n' "${file[0]}" "${file[1]}"
  elif ! [[ -e ${file[0]} && -e ${file[1]} ]]; then
    printf >&2 'Either one or both of the given file does not exists, please try again!%s\n'
  else
    printf 'All ok!\n' && break
  fi
done

printf 'You entered %s and %s\n' "${file[@]}"
```

- The loop continues it does not exit the script until the conditions are satisfied.
- First condition, if file is less than or more than 2.
- Second condition, if both files are the same (same file name).
- Third condition, if both or one of the file does not exists.
- If exiting the script is needed when one of the condition is not satisfied add an `exit 1` inside the `elif` (all of them) block, below/after the line where `printf` statement is.